# Transfer Learning in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

It is possible to download weights for any CNN from the keras repository directly during execution of the program using :

```
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True, input_shape = (224, 224, 3))
```

but is it possible to download the weights trained on imagenet separately and use it to run the CNN model?

Comment: Have you tried: model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5')

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `download the weights trained on imagenet separately and use it to run the CNN model`, It sounds same as the first case. Do you want to download the weights for some model and then use those weights in another (possibly one with a different architecture) model?

Comment: No , I want to download the weights, and say use it anytime I run the model, without downloading it everytime I run the program